# get /static/main/css/main.css http/1.1" 200 717 что это за ошибка?

Tags: css, django, body

Я так и не найду что обозначает данная ошибка. Синтаксис вроде в порядке, тестовый сайт в django запускается.

```
body {
    background: #2c2c2c;
}

aside {
    float: left;
    background: #181818;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 2.5%;
    height: 100vh;
    color: #fff;
    border-right: 5px solid #4d4d4d;
}

aside img {
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
}

aside .logo {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}

aside h3 {
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 35px;
}

aside ul {list-style: none}
aside ul li {
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 20px;
    transition: all .6s ease;
}

aside ul li:hover, aside ul a:hover {
    color: #eb5959;
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

Comment: [200 - успешный запрос](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_HTTP#2xx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эта строка текста является записью журнала веб-сервера, в ней записан запрос, сделанный серверу.

«GET /static/main/css/main.css HTTP/1.1» — эта часть показывает тип запроса (GET), запрашиваемый URL-адрес и используемый протокол (HTTP/1.1).

«200» — эта часть показывает код состояния HTTP, возвращаемый сервером в ответ на запрос. 200 означает «ОК», что указывает на успешный запрос.

«717» — это размер полезной нагрузки ответа в байтах.

В заключение, эта запись в журнале показывает успешный запрос GET для файла CSS «/static/main/css/main.css», а ответ вернулся с кодом состояния 200 и имел размер 717 байт.

Comment: Теперь ясно, спасибо)